# Manipulate order in browserify

Tags: gulp, browserify

I have a manifest file called `all.js` that looks like this:

```js
// Plugins 
var easytabs     = require('./jquery.easytabs.js');
var fancybox     = require('./jquery.fancybox.js');
var imagesloaded = require('./jquery.imagesloaded.js');
var placeholder  = require('./jquery.placeholder.js');
var rating       = require('./jquery.rating.js');
var scrollto     = require('./jquery.scrollTo.js');
var jrespond     = require('./jRespond.js');
var owlcarousel  = require('./owl.carousel.js');
var parsleyext   = require('./parsley.extend.js');
var parsley      = require('./parsley.js');
var parsleycon   = require('./parsleyConditions.js');
var share        = require('./share42.js');

// App
var cart         = require('./cart.js');
var main         = require('./main.js');
var ajaxshell    = require('./ajax-shell.js');
var responsive   = require('./responsive.js');
```

I'm using browserify (alongside Gulp) to bundle all my JavaScript into one file. For my Gulpfile, this is how I'm bundling my JavaScript:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify('./src/frontend/js/all.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/frontend/js/'));
});
```

Whenever it gets outputted though, `main.js` comes before some of the plugins, which is a huge problem as you can imagine. I need all the files under app-specific files to come after the plugins. How can I manipulate the order in which these files are bundled? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `main.js` comes before the plugins in what way, its line number in the bundle? What is the actual problem you're having? A big part of the point of browserify is to make load order of modules not matter. If you're having some issue related to the order the modules appear in the bundle, you may not have your `require()` calls setup right.

Comment: Hi @JMM thanks for the reply. I've updated my question to contain the code necessary to run browserify via my Gulpfile. The problem I'm having is that when my JavaScript gets bundled up into all.js, main.js appears before jQuery and other important dependencies and plugins that should come before. Maybe I'm utilizing browserify wrong. I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Again, what is the *concrete* problem you're having: error message, lack of expected results, etc. `all.js` is the entry file that'll run when the bundle loads. Each of the `require()` calls in it will then run in sequence. It shouldn't matter in what order the modules those `require()` calls reference occur in the bundle source code.